# Server is sending quicker than client can recv

Tags: python, sockets, server, pygame, pickle

my server sends objects much faster than the client receives. That's why the client receives the objects that were sent 10 seconds ago because the client has to receive every object that is in the queue. So my question is: How do I slow the server down or make my client receiving faster?

Edit: I added time.sleep(0.1) to the server but is there a more efficient way?

This is my Network class:

```
import socket
import pickle


class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        self.server = "192.168.1.15"
        self.port = 5555
        self.addr = (self.server, self.port)
        self.player = self.connect()

    def get_player(self):
        return self.player

    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.client.connect(self.addr)
        except:
            pass

    def send_object(self, data):
        self.client.send(pickle.dumps(data))
    
    def get_object(self):
        return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(1024))
      

    def send_msg(self, data):
        self.client.send(bytes(data, "utf-8"))
        

    def get_msg(self):
        return self.client.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
```

and my server when it's sending:

```
p_count = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        if p_count:
            
            games.append(Game(game_id, int(p_count), ip))
            game_id += 1
            while True:
                conn.send(pickle.dumps(games[-1]))
```

and my client when it's receiving:

```
def update(self):
        global bg_surface
        try:
            self.game = n.get_object()
            self.player_in = self.game.players_ready
            bg_surface = pygame.image.load('./bilder/background3.jpg').convert()
            bg_surface = pygame.transform.scale(bg_surface, (screen_width, screen_height))
            self.warte_text = Label(f"Warte auf Spieler {self.player_in}/{self.player_amount}", 20, (screen_width // 2, screen_height // 2 * 0.25), (255, 0, 0))
            self.warte_text.update(bg_surface)
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: You’ll have to make changes to your protocol so your client can tell your server either ‘send me some now’ or ‘pause for x seconds’, something like that, because otherwise the server doesn’t know the rate the client can take the data. Or if you can’t send this from client to server then the server will have to be slowed down to a rate the client can always be guaranteed to accept whcih doesn’t seem a very robust approach.

Answer (score 1):

The efficient way to handle this is to have your server call [select()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html) or [poll()](https://pythontic.com/modules/select/poll) on the socket to find out when the socket has room in its outgoing-data-buffer (and optionally block until there is room) and only generate and `send()` data to the socket when the socket has indicated it is ready-for-write.  That way your server-thread doesn't get blocked waiting for the client to read data, no matter how slow the client is at reading.

Comment: Thanks, but how exactly can I do this? I do not fully understand the documentation.

Comment: Google "python select tutorial" and a bunch of links will come up, read through them (and you're right, `select()` is a bit difficult to understand at first, but it's worth learning how to use since it allows you to do a lot of things that aren't otherwise possible in a single thread, like handle multiple sockets at once)